# Should a tag be added?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently came across [This Question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6590/voltmeter-with-usb-rs232).

The only tag that the user could put this under and the only one that I could find was "usb".

After a search of all available tags the only other one I found would be "home-electronics"

Would it be appropriate to add this under "home-electronics" or should a new tag for "test-equipment" be made.

If it is the latter I will add it.  I am just looking for some input here.

Comment: Since it has been 4 days and I have gotten only crickets I have added this tag.  Would still appreciated the input.

Comment: chirp chirp  *calling all mods, calling all mods* :P